# Hibernate Many to Many cascade save with join table

Tags: java, hibernate

So here is what I am trying to accomplish, if it is at all possible.
I am trying to save the following objects the the DB using a cascade.

This is a simplified example of the issue I am running into.  The way I see it working is that hibernate should insert "User" then "Group" then "UserGroup" in that order, but what is happening is it's inserting "User" then "UserGroup" which causes the "object references an unsaved transient instance" error for Group in the log below.

Obviously saving individual objects with their own save() call works but the real database is much larger than this and I would prefer to avoid that.

The "TestCode" below replicates how the data is coming to me, which gets de-serialized from JSON data.

I suspect it has something to do with my mapping but I cannot pinpoint the cause.

For reference I am using Hibernate 5.2.10.Final.

So what am I missing?

[DB Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nygPL.png)

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -7899020279254796671L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "userID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private int userId;

@Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 45)
private String name;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "id.user")
private Set<UserGroup> userGroups = new HashSet<UserGroup>(0);
//Getters, setters, etc...
}
```

Group.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Group")
public class Group implements java.io.Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 4428563096071107683L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "groupID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private int groupId;

@Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 45)
private String name;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "id.group")
private Set<UserGroup> userGroups = new HashSet<UserGroup>(0);
}
```

UserGroup.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "UserGroup")
public class UserGroup implements java.io.Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 5495027289164828327L;

@EmbeddedId    
private UserGroupId id;

@Column(name = "defaultGroup")
private Boolean defaultGroup;
}
```

UserGroupdId.java

```
@Embeddable
public class UserGroupId implements java.io.Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -3806643465171954306L;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "groupID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Group group;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "userID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private User user;
}
```

TestCode

```
User u = new User();
u.setName("User");

Group g = new Group();
g.setName("Group");


UserGroup ug = new UserGroup();
UserGroupId id = new UserGroupId();
ug.setId(id);
ug.getId().setGroup(g);
ug.getId().setUser(u);

ug.setDefaultGroup(false);
u.getUserGroups().add(ug);


session.saveOrUpdate(u);
```

Log Entry

```
[DEBUG] 2017-08-03 10:19:43.497 [main] SQL - insert into M2M.User (name) values (?)
[DEBUG] 2017-08-03 10:19:43.497 [main] SQL - insert into M2M.User (name) values (?)
[TRACE] 2017-08-03 10:19:43.510 [main] BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [User]
[TRACE] 2017-08-03 10:19:43.510 [main] BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [User]
[DEBUG] 2017-08-03 10:19:43.541 [main] IdentifierGeneratorHelper - Natively generated identity: 65
[DEBUG] 2017-08-03 10:19:43.541 [main] ResourceRegistryStandardImpl - HHH000387: ResultSet's statement was not registered
[DEBUG] 2017-08-03 10:19:43.546 [main] SQL - select usergroup_.groupID, usergroup_.userID, usergroup_.defaultGroup as defaultG1_2_ from M2M.UserGroup usergroup_ where usergroup_.groupID=? and usergroup_.userID=?
[DEBUG] 2017-08-03 10:19:43.546 [main] SQL - select usergroup_.groupID, usergroup_.userID, usergroup_.defaultGroup as defaultG1_2_ from M2M.UserGroup usergroup_ where usergroup_.groupID=? and usergroup_.userID=?
[ERROR] 2017-08-03 10:19:43.546 [main] M2MTest - org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance beforeQuery flushing: m2m.Group
```

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany#Bi-directional_Many_to_Many

Answer (score 2):

It makes no sense to cascade from [`@ManyToOne`](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/) associations.

Also, cascading the `REMOVE` operations for many-to-many associations makes no sense either because both mapped entities are parents while the join table is the child in this association.

So, you have two choices:

1. If you want to map the [`join table`](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/), you need to save the `User` and the `Group` separately and cascade to `UserGroup` when you set both sides of the association.
2. You can skip mapping the join table and the cascading will work as you expect. However, make sure you use a [`Set`](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) instead of a `List` when mapping a collection association.